# In linux btrfs, how can I know in advance how many disk space will be freed when a snapshot(subvolume) be deleted?

Tags: linux, filesystems

As btrfs has the feature of data redundancy, some files in continuous snapshots may mapped to one physical data. When I want to delete a snapshot to free some disk space, some file in disk may not be real freed.

So are there any method to get the free disk space info before snapshot be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't. A snapshot doesn't know how much data it owns exclusively until it runs a full scan over all of its blocks/extents.